# cannot resolve routing for action

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I´m creating a Web-API with a controller like this:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    private readonly Product[] m_products = {
        new Product {Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1},
        new Product {Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M},
        new Product {Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M}
    };

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return this.m_products;
    }


    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("ById")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetProductById(int id)
    {
        var product = this.m_products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        return product == null ? (IHttpActionResult) NotFound() : Ok(product);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("ByName")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetProductByName(string name)
    {
        var product = this.m_products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
        return product == null ? (IHttpActionResult) NotFound() : Ok(product);
    }
}
```

Within my `WebApiConfig` I have this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

So in fact I´m trying to have two actions on my `ProductController`. However I can´t seem to get the second one to work. Thuis when I run `myServer/api/products/ById/1` I get the first element from my list. However when I try `myServer/api/products/ByName/Hammer` I get an Http-error not found (404). I also tried the URL in lowercase with the same result.

Comment: Because your parameter is named `name` not `id`.

Comment: Your routes are not RESTful.  Might consider changing to something like:
"products/{id:int}"
"products/{name}"

Comment: Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) and

Reference [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly specify the  pattern using `Route()` attribute for your action method like:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("ByName")]
[Route("api/Products/ByName/{name}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetProductByName(string name)
{
    var product = this.m_products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
    return product == null ? (IHttpActionResult) NotFound() : Ok(product);
}
```

Please refer to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) for more details.

Comment: I still get "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:57665/api/products/ByName/Hammer'.".

Comment: @HimBromBeere with attribute routing he is probably missing the `RoutePrefix("api/products")` route prefix attribute on the controller, or include the entire expected route on the action

Comment: @Nkosi is right, you need to prefix  the whole url that would be generated

Comment: @HimBromBeere you should read that official documentation i linked, there are multiple  way to handle this, so reading docs should help

Comment: Yeah, got it. The route should contain the *entire* route, including the àpi`-part and the controller.

Comment: yes, it can only  contain that name and parameter too but then we need to decorate the controller as @Namira pointed out in his post.

Answer (score 3):

Your RouteConfig is defined as this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

But your `ByName` action takes a `name` parameter, not `id`.

You need to create a route that takes a `name` parameter.

You can do this easily by decorating your action:

```
[Route("ByName/{name}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetProductByName(string name)
```

I forgot you also need to include the [`RoutePrefix`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.routeprefixattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attribute on your controller.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/products")]
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
```

Comment: I thought, `{id}` is just a placeholder for *any value*. Didn´t know it must be named `id` in the args-list as well.

Comment: @HimBromBeere yeah that tripped me up a while back too.  Check out the [`[Route()]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.route(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute for your actions

Answer (score 3):

One of the options is to use `Route` attribute to specify routes to your resources. For your case it would look like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Products")]
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    private readonly Product[] m_products = {
        new Product {Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1},
        new Product {Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M},
        new Product {Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M}
    };

    //GET api/products
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return this.m_products;
    }

    //GET api/products/ById/1
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("ById/{id:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetProductById(int id)
    {
        var product = this.m_products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        return product == null ? (IHttpActionResult) NotFound() : Ok(product);
    }

    //GET api/products/ByName/Hammer
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("ByName/{name}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetProductByName(string name)
    {
        var product = this.m_products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
        return product == null ? (IHttpActionResult) NotFound() : Ok(product);
    }
}
```

Comment: @HimBromBeere Keep what you have. They will work in tandem